# How can I tell when I've completed a major Quest (the kind I can start a game from)?

Tags: diablo-iii

When I go to change my quest, there are specific Quests I can start from

How can I tell in-game when I've completed one of these Quests, and started the next one?

I dislike quitting my current game to go play with someone else, only to return and realize I have to re-do some quests again because I stopped in the middle of a quest chain

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to be sure your progress is saved is to keep going until you reach a **main quest with a new name**. The quest name is shown both in the quest log (J) and on the list to the right.

As for the substages on each quest (the ones listed under "change quest" at main menu), I don't know a way to tell when you've reached them without knowing beforehand where the breakpoints are in each quest.